# Examples of Non-Hausdorff Topology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, reference-request

When I learned real analysis and topology courses, most of the spaces are Hausdorff. I only know Zariski topology and étale topology for non-Hausdorff ones that play important roles in algebraic geometry. Are there more important examples of non-Hausdorff topology? Any answers and references are welcome.

Comment: Scott topologies (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_continuity)) play a role in theoretical computer science and other fields close to logic. They are often non-Hausdorff too. Also the digital line (and its square) is a commonly cited example to model pixels on screen.

Comment: This thread from a little over a month ago has quite a few interesting answers: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3778134/naturally-occurring-non-hausdorff-spaces/3778177#3778177

Comment: @Henno Brandsma thank you

Comment: @Tabes Bridges thank you, it seems I didn't search well

Answer (score 1):

The $\mathcal{L}^p$ **function** spaces are an example one usually does not think of as a non Hausdorff topology. In practice one jumps between $\mathcal{L}^p$ and the corresponding Hausdorffization
$$L^p = \mathcal{L}^p \big/ \{0\}^{\textrm{cl}},$$
as working with representatives, i.e. functions instead of equivalence classes, is more intuitive in many places.

Another notable class of examples arises in Oid-Geometry: the total space of all arrows in a Lie groupoid is non Hausdorff in many important examples such as the Monodromy and the Holonomy groupoids.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, does the non-Hausdorffness of $\mathcal{L}^p$ play important role somewhere?

Comment: Only in the sense that one immediately sets out to fix that by passing to $L^p$ instead. Most of the interesting theorems only hold for the equivalence classes.

Comment: okay, thank you